# Is it possible to integrate rabbitmq and kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I'm trying to do a POC where we need to connect RabbitMQ and Kafka. My question is
whether its possible to connect RabbitMQ and Kafka? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think these connectors are useful : https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-rabbitmq/   ,   https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-rabbitmq

Comment: Short answer: it's possible to connect Kafka with almost anything... The question you should be asking is how to write that code...

Answer (score 1):

In short Yes,
 Its possible to connect RabbitMQ and Kafka.
 There are two ways to achieve it.

- Open source Kafka connector from Jcustenborder https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-rabbitmq
- RabbitMQ Kafka connector under a Confluent enterprise license version. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-rabbitmq/index.html

How to Install install those kafka connector to achieve goal?

1. For open source connector, Build the project then take the jar file or download from maven repo and place jar file inside kafka connector plugin (docker) at path usr/share/java. Then restart the plugin or docker container.
2. For RabbitMQ Kafka connector under a Confluent, follow the instructions in web page.

   Note : Kafka-connect-rabbitMQ git repo from Jcustenborder is not available.but maven repo and forked off repository are available

   - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect/kafka-connect-rabbitmq
   - https://github.com/osterzel/kafka-connect-rabbitmq